# Embedding complex tables in a journal template

Tags: tables, templates, journal-publishing, journal

I spent an inordinate amount of time creating 2 beautiful tables for a manuscript. Paper accepted!

Turns out the journal wants *either* Word or LaTeX, but not a mix, and the *tables must be in the main text itself*, not separate.

This leaves me with two options:

1. Convert the tables to Word
2. Rewrite the paper in LaTeX (still doing most writing in Word).

(2) Seemed to be the logical choice, and I was making progress until I realized my tables can't simply cut and paste into the LaTeX document. There are all sorts of clashing errors that are extremely unfriendly to newbies. They are also **landscape (wide) tables**, which isn't helping.

I tried (1) using **pandoc**, but I get absolute garbage - jibberish and missing 90% of the text.

Table Text as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article} 
% Make Landscape
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
% dcolumn to line up decimals
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Table} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
% The above two to allow that last line with the dagger as a bottom note.
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}
% Eliminates the space between the caption and the table itself.

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
 \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Regression models linking number of pregnancies to telomere length (models 1-4) and DNAmAge (models 5-8).} 
  \label{table2} 
\begin{tabular}{
>{\bfseries}l
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Telomere Length~}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{DNAmAge~}} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)$^{\dagger}$}\\ 
% You need the $ to 'leave' the text and get back to a command

\hline \\[-1.8ex] 

%%%%%%%%%

 Age & -0.047 & -0.029 & -0.028 & -0.029 & 0.485 & 0.667 & 0.656 & 0.645 \\ 
  & p = 0.003^{**} & p = 0.071^{+} & p = 0.073^{+} & p = 0.068^{+} & p = 0.293 & p = 0.157 & p = 0.158 & p = 0.165 \\ 
  No.Pregnancies & -0.014 & -0.013 & -0.014 & -0.016 & 0.363 & 0.326 & 0.459 & 0.510 \\ 
  & p = 0.025^{*} & p = 0.039^{*} & p = 0.031^{*} & p = 0.020^{*} & p = 0.026^{*} & p = 0.049^{*} & p = 0.007^{**} & p = 0.005^{**} \\ 
  SES &  & -0.006 & -0.006 & -0.004 &  & -0.180 & -0.214 & -0.291 \\ 
  &  & p = 0.143 & p = 0.161 & p = 0.395 &  & p = 0.146 & p = 0.081^{+} & p = 0.055^{+} \\ 
  Currently Pregnant (Y) &  &  & 0.011 & 0.011 &  &  & -1.472 & -1.460 \\ 
  &  &  & p = 0.534 & p = 0.540 &  &  & p = 0.001^{**} & p = 0.001^{**} \\ 
  No.Pregnancies x SES &  &  &  & -0.004 &  &  &  & 0.106 \\ 
  &  &  &  & p = 0.362 &  &  &  & p = 0.385 \\ 
  Intercept & 1.826 & 1.337 & 1.332 & 1.343 & 14.818 & 10.319 & 10.611 & 10.850 \\ 
  & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p = 0.138 & p = 0.318 & p = 0.297 & p = 0.287 \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\normalfont{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} \\ 
\normalfont{Adjusted R$^{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.015} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.063} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.062} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.062} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.011} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.041} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.067} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.067} \\ 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  
\end{tabular} 
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item $^{\dagger}$Marked models include controls for top 10 principal components of genetic variation and average urbanicity-score (complete results in Supplementary Table S1).
      +p\textless{0.1};
      *p\textless0.05;
      **p\textless0.01;
      ***p\textless0.001 
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Journal (*Scientific Reports*) Template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-submissions-to-scientific-reports/xyrztqvdccns#.WwnIHqlOmRs)

**Please help!** I have been trying to transition to LaTeX (with R and RMarkdown) and convince others this is a good idea, but am seriously let down when I can't even embed a simple table into a pre-existing template!

Comment: i can compile your table without any problem, (no errors, no warnings, no bad boxes). however, i don't understand meaning of  `p = 0.031^{*}`, since in notes you inform reader that `*` means `*: p \textless 0.05` ... welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Thanks for you kindness. It makes up for the pain of trying to learn! 
I also can compile the table. But I can't 'embed' it within the Journal Template. Or are you able to do this?

Comment: @CPR: Did you also use the relevant packages (`threeparttale`, `booktabs`,   `dcolumn`,...)  in the template?

Comment: Simple Table: For me, tables are one of the toughest challenges with LaTeX :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - Actually, creating good and appealing tables tends to be a challenge in *any* typesetting system, not just LaTeX.

Comment: @Mico Maybe I have another Best-Of of LaTeX as you have, but I get your point. I just wanted to make the OP less sceptical about LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should  aim to declutter the look of the table, say by moving the "p-value" reminders into the header column. Incidentally, don't bother showing the p-values of the intercept terms: Nobody cares whether these terms are significant or not.

Also, do provide more structure to the `d` columns; that'll tighten up the look of the table tremendously. I'd also remove all **bold-facing**: it doesn't actually help make the table more readable or understandable. Since you're loading the `booktabs` package anyway, you might as well (should?!) use its line-drawing macros instead of the generic-LaTeX `\hline` directive. And, since you're loading the `threeparttable` environment, why not also make use of the `\tnote` macro for the "dagger" markers in the second header row.

Off-topic: Is "urbanicity" a real word? Might "urbanization" work for you? In my view, the term "urbanicity" is particularly unfortunate as it contains the particles "urb[is]" and "city" -- two terms for, well, cities...

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{wlscirep} % see https://github.com/SFICSSS16-CircularEconomy/Documents/blob/master
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn} % dcolumn to line up decimals
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Table} 
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}% no extra space below caption

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Regression models linking number of pregnancies to telomere length (models 1--4) and DNAmAge (models 5--8).} 
\label{table2} 

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{d{2.5}} @{}} % note: "d{2.5}", not "d{3}"
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Telomere Length} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{DNAmAge} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
& \mc{(1)} & \mc{(2)\tnote{$\dagger$}} & \mc{(3)\tnote{$\dagger$}} 
& \mc{(4)\tnote{$\dagger$}} & \mc{(5)} & \mc{(6)\tnote{$\dagger$}} 
& \mc{(7)\tnote{$\dagger$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{(8)\tnote{$\dagger$}}\\ 

\midrule

Age & -0.047 & -0.029 & -0.028 & -0.029 & 0.485 & 0.667 & 0.656 & 0.645 \\ 
\quad$p$-values&0.003^{**} &0.071^{+} &0.073^{+} &0.068^{+} &0.293 &0.157 &0.158 &0.165 \\ \addlinespace
No.Pregnancies & -0.014 & -0.013 & -0.014 & -0.016 & 0.363 & 0.326 & 0.459 & 0.510 \\ 
\quad$p$-values&0.025^{*} &0.039^{*} &0.031^{*} &0.020^{*} &0.026^{*} &0.049^{*} &0.007^{**} &0.005^{**} \\ \addlinespace
SES &  & -0.006 & -0.006 & -0.004 &  & -0.180 & -0.214 & -0.291 \\ 
\quad$p$-values&  &0.143 &0.161 &0.395 &  &0.146 &0.081^{+} &0.055^{+} \\ \addlinespace
Currently Pregnant (Y) &  &  & 0.011 & 0.011 &  &  & -1.472 & -1.460 \\ 
\quad$p$-values&  &  &0.534 &0.540 &  &  &0.001^{**} &0.001^{**} \\ \addlinespace
No.Pregnancies $\times$ SES &  &  &  & -0.004 &  &  &  & 0.106 \\ 
\quad$p$-values&  &  &  &0.362 &  &  &  &0.385 \\ \addlinespace
Intercept & 1.826 & 1.337 & 1.332 & 1.343 & 14.818 & 10.319 & 10.611 & 10.850 \\ 
%% One usually doesn't show p-values for the intercept terms ...
%& p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} &0.138 &0.318 &0.297 &0.287 \\ 
\midrule

Observations & \mc{821} & \mc{821} & \mc{821} & \mc{821} & \mc{397} 
             & \mc{397} & \mc{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{397} \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & \mc{0.015} & \mc{0.063} & \mc{0.062} & \mc{0.062} 
     & \mc{0.011} & \mc{0.041} & \mc{0.067} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{0.067} \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\begin{tablenotes}

\small
\item[$\dagger$]Marked models include controls for top 10 principal components of 
genetic variation and average urbanicity score (complete results in 
Supplementary Table S1).

$^{+}\ p<0.1$; $^{*}\ p<0.05$; $^{**}\ p<0.01$; $^{***}\ p<0.001$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: p.s. And yes, "Urbanicity" is a word. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the table embedded in the template. It fits perfectly well with a simple modification; instead of the `p =` scattered everywhere, put the p-value inside two parens `(..)`. Also the `@{}` will give you some more space. You can even gain more space by combining all four instances of `p < 0.001^{**}` into one.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}

\usepackage{dcolumn} 
% dcolumn to line up decimals
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Table} 
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} 
% The above two to allow that last line with the dagger as a bottom note.
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt}

\title{Scientific Reports Title to see here (20 words or less)}
\author[1,*]{Alice Author}
\author[2]{Bob Author}
\author[1,2,+]{Christine Author}
\author[2,+]{Derek Author}
\affil[1]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}
\affil[2]{Affiliation, department, city, postcode, country}
\affil[*]{corresponding.author@email.example}
\affil[+]{these authors contributed equally to this work}

%\keywords{Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3}
\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\end{abstract}
\begin{document}

\flushbottom
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent Please note: Abbreviations should be introduced at the first mention in the main text – no abbreviations lists. Suggested structure of main text (not enforced) is provided below.

\section*{Introduction}

The Introduction section, of referenced text\cite{Figueredo:2009dg} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

\begin{table}[!htb] \centering 
 \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Regression models linking number of pregnancies to telomere length (models 1-4) and DNAmAge (models 5-8).} 
  \label{table2} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}
>{\bfseries}l
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} 
D{.}{.}{3} } 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Telomere Length~}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{DNAmAge~}} \\ 
\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)$^{\dagger}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(8)$^{\dagger}$}\\ 
% You need the $ to 'leave' the text and get back to a command
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
%%%%%%%%%
 Age & -0.047 & -0.029 & -0.028 & -0.029 & 0.485 & 0.667 & 0.656 & 0.645 \\ 
  & (0.003)^{**} & (0.071)^{+} & (0.073)^{+} & (0.068)^{+} & (0.293) & (0.157) & (0.158) & (0.165) \\ 
  No. Pregnancies & -0.014 & -0.013 & -0.014 & -0.016 & 0.363 & 0.326 & 0.459 & 0.510 \\ 
  & (0.025)^{*} & (0.039)^{*} & (0.031)^{*} & (0.020)^{*} & (0.026)^{*} & (0.049)^{*} & (0.007)^{**} & (0.005)^{**} \\ 
  SES &  & -0.006 & -0.006 & -0.004 &  & -0.180 & -0.214 & -0.291 \\ 
  &  & (0.143) & (0.161) & (0.395) &  & (0.146) & (0.081)^{+} & (0.055)^{+} \\ 
  Currently Pregnant (Y) &  &  & 0.011 & 0.011 &  &  & -1.472 & -1.460 \\ 
  &  &  & (0.534) & (0.540) &  &  & (0.001)^{**} & (0.001)^{**} \\ 
  No. Pregnancies x SES &  &  &  & -0.004 &  &  &  & 0.106 \\ 
  &  &  &  & (0.362) &  &  &  & (0.385) \\ 
  Intercept & 1.826 & 1.337 & 1.332 & 1.343 & 14.818 & 10.319 & 10.611 & 10.850 \\ 
  & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & p < 0.001^{**} & (0.138) & (0.318) & (0.297) & (0.287) \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\normalfont{Observations} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{821} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{397} \\ 
\normalfont{Adjusted R$^{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.015} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.063} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.062} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.062} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.011} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.041} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.067} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.067} \\ 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\hline \\[-1.8ex]  
\end{tabular} 
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item$^{\dagger}$Marked models include controls for top 10 principal components of genetic variation and average urbanicity-score (complete results in Supplementary Table S1).
      +p\textless{0.1};
      *p\textless0.05;
      **p\textless0.01;
      ***p\textless0.001 
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't test this right this second but thanks already for your help and if this works, double thanks! Tex community is fast and helpful AND kind?! Yes!

Comment: p.s. Sorry I can't upvote I don't have the reputation.

Comment: With the setting `D{.}{.}{3}`, the column contents aren't centered all that well. This may be seen in how `(1)`, `(2)`, etc are placed in the column headers. Better to specify `D{.}{.}{2.5}`. And, consider writing `*{8}{D{.}{.}{<whatever>}` instead of having 8 separate `D` statements.

Answer (score 2):

**edit:**
please apology me for disturbances at uploading my answer. i first time use overleaf and have unexpected problems :-(

now seems that i succeed to manage them :-)

[image]

similarly as [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/59109/aboammar) i suggest to change unusual notation for `p` values (see my comment below question). other suggestion is mostly off-topic, however, it can help you in at your other tables design:

- for instead of `\hline`s are used rules from package `booktabs`
- removed are all `\\[-1.8ex]` as unnecessary clutter (rules from `booktabs` better manage vertical spaces between rows)
- introduced are two `\newcommand`s for shorter writing code in table
- code for content of table already in editor mimic final view of table (on this way you can more easy navigate through your table

```
\documentclass[fleqn,10pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}       % for nice rules in table
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % dcolumn to line up decimals
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\newcommand\mcbf[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0ex}

\usepackage{lipsum}         % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Regression models linking number of pregnancies to telomere length (models 1-4) and DNAmAge (models 5-8).}
  \label{table2}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
    >{\bfseries}l
    *{8}{D{.}{.}{5}}
                }
%%%% column headers
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Telomere Length~}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{DNAmAge~}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-9}
    & \mcbf{(1)}                & \mcbf{(2)$)^{\dagger}$}   & \mcbf{(3)$)^{\dagger}$}
    & \mcbf{(4)$^{\dagger}$}    & \mcbf{(5)}                & \mcbf{(6)$^{\dagger}$}
    & \mcbf{(7)$^{\dagger}$}    & \mcbf{(8)$^{\dagger}$}                                    \\
    \midrule
%%%% table body
 Age    & -0.047        & -0.029        & -0.028        & -0.029
        & 0.485         & 0.667         & 0.656         & 0.645                             \\
        & (0.003)^{**}  & (0.071)^{+}   & (0.073)^{+}   & (0.068)^{+}
        & (0.293        & (0.157        & (0.158        & (0.165                            \\
No.Pregnancies
        & -0.014        & -0.013        & -0.014        & -0.016
        & 0.363         & 0.326         & 0.459         & 0.510                             \\
        & (0.025)^{*}   & (0.039)^{*}   & (0.031)^{*}   & (0.020)^{*}
        & (0.026)^{*}   & (0.049)^{*}   & (0.007)^{**}  & (0.005)^{**}                      \\
SES     &               & -0.006        & -0.006        & -0.004
        &               & -0.180        & -0.214        & -0.291                            \\
        &               & (0.143        & (0.161        & (0.395
        &               & (0.146        & (0.081)^{+}   & (0.055)^{+}                       \\
Currently Pregnant (Y)
        &               &               & 0.011         & 0.011
        &               &               & -1.472        & -1.460                            \\
        &               &               & (0.534        & (0.540
        &               &               & (0.001)^{**}  & (0.001)^{**}                      \\
No.Pregnancies x SES
        &               &               &               & -0.004
        &               &               &               & 0.106                             \\
        &               &               &               & (0.362
        &               &               &               & (0.385                            \\
Intercept & 1.826         & 1.337         & 1.332         & 1.343
        & 14.818        & 10.319        & 10.611        & 10.850                            \\
        & p < 0.001     & p < 0.001     & p < 0.001     &  p < 0.001
        & (0.138)       & (0.318)       & (0.297)       & (0.287)                           \\
    \midrule
\normalfont Observations
        & \mc{821}      & \mc{821}      & \mc{821}          & \mc{821}
        & \mc{397}      & \mc{397}      & \mc{397}          & \mc{397}                      \\
\normalfont Adjusted R$)^{2}$
        & \mc{0.015}    & \mc{0.063}    & \mc{0.062}        & \mc{0.062}
        & \mc{0.011}    & \mc{0.041}    & \mc{0.067}        & \mc{0.067}                    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
%%%% table notes

    \begin{tablenotes}[para]\small
\item[$^{\dagger}$] Marked models include controls for top 10 principal components of genetic variation and average urbanicity-score (complete results in Supplementary Table S1).

\item[+]    $p < 0.1$;
\item[*]    $p < 0.05$;
\item[**]   $p < 0.01$;
\item[***]  $p < 0.001$.
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```